# Why need to perform a formatType check when implement a ICustomFormatter interface in C#?

Tags: c#, string, formatting, globalization

I am reading C#6.0 in a nutshell, in the book it says user can also write their own format provider that works in conjunction with existing types. And on page 245 there is a sample code as below:

I don't know if the check could be omitted when implement GetFormat function? Can I just use

```
return this
```

instead of

```
if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)) 
    return this;
return null;
```

in that implementation? As I think formatType will always be typeof ICustomFormatter as per class declaration, because it implemented the ICustomFormatter interface?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace Page245
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double n = -123.45;
            IFormatProvider fp = new WordyFormatProvider();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(fp, "{0:C} in words is {0:W}", n));
        }
        public class WordyFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
        {
            static readonly string[] _numberWords =
            "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine minus point".Split();
            IFormatProvider _parent;   // Allows consumers to chain format providers
            public WordyFormatProvider() : this(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { }
            public WordyFormatProvider(IFormatProvider parent)
            {
                _parent = parent;
            }
            public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
            {
                if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)) // Can this check be omitted?, just return this directly, as formatType will always be typeof ICustomFormatter as per class declaration, it implements the ICustomFormatter interface??
                    return this;
                return null;
            }
            public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider prov)
            {
                // If it's not our format string, defer to the parent provider:
                if (arg == null || format != "W")
                    return string.Format(_parent, "{0:" + format + "}", arg);
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                string digitList = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", arg);
                foreach (char digit in digitList)
                {
                    int i = "0123456789-.".IndexOf(digit);
                    if (i == -1) continue;
                    if (result.Length > 0) result.Append(' ');
                    result.Append(_numberWords[i]);
                }
                return result.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have changed code and the results doesn't seem to change, but I would like to ask if there is any potential downside if I modify the code like mentioned? Thanks for any comments or answer.

It writes to console as below and result doesn't change after modification
    -€123.45 in words is minus one two three point four five

Comment: "*as formatType will always be typeof ICustomFormatter*" -- what makes you think that? It might be called with `typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo)` or `typeof(NumberFormatInfo)`

Comment: @canton7 thanks for kind comments. I am new to csharp. I am thinking that when consume that WordyFormatProvider class the code will possible be Console.WriteLine(string.Format(fp, "{0:C} in words is {0:W}", n)); And fp is instance of WordyFormatProvider that implemented ICustomFormatter interface? Could you give me an example that the result will differ after modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times when `IFormatProvider.GetFormat` is called with `formatType` set to something *other* than your formatter type.

Let's use a really simple test `IFormatProvider`:

```
public class CustomFormatter : IFormatProvider
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called with " + formatType);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, let's try some things:

```
string s = 3.ToString(new CustomFormatter());
```

Here, `GetFormat` is called with `typeof(NumberFormatInfo)`.

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString(new CustomFormatter());
```

Here, `GetFormat` is called with `typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo)`.

```
string s = string.Format(new CustomFormatter(), "{0}", 3);
```

Here, `GetFormat` is first called with `typeof(ICustomFormatter)`, and then with `typeof(NumberFormatInfo)`.

---

Now it's true that in the *current* implementation of .NET, if you pass your own `IFormatProvider` to `string.Format`, it will first ask it for an `ICustomFormatter`, and if that returns `null`, for an `NumberFormatInfo` / `DateTimeFormatInfo` (if appropriate).

**However**, you cannot rely on this. Someone might use your `IFormatProvider` somewhere else (e.g. passing to an object which implements `IFormattable`), in which case your `IFormatProvider` might be asked for a different `formatType`. It might be that the implementation of `string.Format` changes in the future, and it asks for a `NumberFormatInfo` *before* or *as well as* an `ICustomFormatter`.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider.getformat?view=netframework-4.8) for `IFormatProvider.GetFormat` say:

> **Returns**
>
> An instance of the object specified by `formatType`, if the `IFormatProvider` implementation can supply that type of object; otherwise, `null`.

For everything to work, now and in the future, you need to follow this. If your `IFormatProvider` can supply an instance of the requested type, it should do so. Otherwise, it should return `null`.

---

As for why `string.Format` first calls our `CustomFormatter` with `typeof(ICustomFormatter)`, and then with `typeof(NumberFormatInfo)`, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#how-arguments-are-formatted):

> **How arguments are formatted**
>
> Format items are processed sequentially from the beginning of the string. Each format item has an index that corresponds to an object in the method's argument list. The Format method retrieves the argument and derives its string representation as follows:
>
> - If the argument is `null`, the method inserts `String.Empty` into the result string. You don't have to be concerned with handling a `NullReferenceException` for `null` arguments.
> - If you call the `Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])` overload and the provider object's `IFormatProvider.GetFormat` implementation returns a non-null `ICustomFormatter` implementation, the argument is passed to its `ICustomFormatter.Format(String, Object, IFormatProvider)` method. If the format item includes a `formatString` argument, it is passed as the first argument to the method. If the `ICustomFormatter` implementation is available and produces a non-null string, that string is returned as the string representation of the argument; otherwise, the next step executes.
> - If the argument implements the `IFormattable` interface, its `IFormattable.ToString` implementation is called.
> - The argument's parameterless `ToString` method, which either overrides or inherits from a base class implementation, is called.

The argument is not `null`, so we skip the first bullet.

We called the overload of `string.Format` which takes an `IFormatProvider`, but our `IFormatProvider.GetFormat` implementation returned `null`, so we skip over the second bullet.

Our argument, an `Int32`, *does* implement `IFormattable`, so its `IFormattable.ToString` implementation is called (and our `IFormatProvider` is passed in). `Int32.ToString(IFormatProvider provider)` calls `IFormatProvider.GetFormat` and passes in `typeof(NumberFormatInfo)`.

Comment: Hi @canton7 I really appreciate your kind help on clarify this. I am reading the book and running all code and try to make sure I understand what the author wants reader to learn in each code snippets . Thanks.

Comment: Hi @canton7 why string s = string.Format(new CustomFormatter(), "{0}", 3); is first called with typeof(ICustomFormatter), and then with typeof(NumberFormatInfo)? Could you explain in details?

Comment: @HuibinZhang Added an explanation onto the end of my answer

Comment: HI @canton7, as you said "Our argument, an Int32, does implement IFormattable, so its IFormattable.ToString implementation is called (and our IFormatProvider is passed in)." I think  the word 'our IFormatProvider' you mean the IFormatProvider of Int32 object not the CustomFormatter we defined, is that correct? thank

Comment: @HuibinZhang There's no such thing as "the `IFormatProvider` of Int32 object". `Int32.ToString(IFormatProvider)` *accepts* an `IFormatProvider`, and `string.Format` will pass in the `IFormatProvider` you gave it: in our case, the `CustomFormatter`

Comment: Specifically, [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,1464)

Comment: Hi @canton7 sorry to keeping on asking you, if it pass in CustomFormatter, then Int32.ToString(IFormatProvider) is taking CustomFormatter as parameter, but the implementation of GetFormat returns null, how can "Int32.ToString(IFormatProvider provider) calls IFormatProvider.GetFormat and passes in typeof(NumberFormatInfo) happen?"

Comment: Hi @canton7 maybe your answer "Now it's true that in the current implementation of .NET, if you pass your own IFormatProvider to string.Format, it will first ask it for an ICustomFormatter, and if that returns null, for an NumberFormatInfo / DateTimeFormatInfo (if appropriate)." already explained this previous question? If that returns null then it will look for an NumberFormatInfo / DateTimeFormatInfo (if appropriate)? I feel it is a bit hard to understand what all happening in the background, but I sometimes really want to know details of what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206026/discussion-between-huibin-zhang-and-canton7).